# Youtube/online videos lag with FF/Chromium HTML5/Flash after upgrading to 13.04

Tags: firefox, video, flash, chromium, html5

Running Lubuntu 13.04-64 and I can't seem to be able to watch HD videos in a browser anymore after upgrading to 13.04 from 12.10.

Tried FF and Chromium. HTML5 and Flash.

I have a dualcore atom processor with a Nvidia ION GPU and I can watch 1080p high bitrate 264h with VLC/MPlayer without any lag.

What can I do?

Comment: I have a similar setup on my laptop, is the screen 1080p, or just 720p?

Comment: Screen was WXGA (1280x1024), unfortunately the crt monitor decided to become toast this morning. Now I'm left with a 1080p led screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround: install `minitube`, a desktop youtube application. More info: http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube